# grpc dart server and client exmple with secure connection

Tags: dart, security, protocol-buffers, grpc, credentials

I have searched for grpc **secure** server and client example in dart I couldn't find any, example of creating **insecure connection** can be found but this is not what I am looking for.

I have managed to compile it with secure but getting grpc error when connecting between client to server

> Caught error: gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message:
> Error connecting: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during
> handshake, details: null, rawResponse: null)

My Server credentials implementation:

```
final String myPath = 'password_file.pem';
final File f = File(myPath);
final Uint8List bytes = f.readAsBytesSync();

final server = Server(
  [myPbServer()],
  const <Interceptor>[],
  CodecRegistry(codecs: const [GzipCodec(), IdentityCodec()]),
);
await server.serve(
  port: 6053,
  security: ServerTlsCredentials(certificate: bytes),
);
```

My client credentials implementation:

```
final String myPath = 'password_file.pem';
final File f = File(myPath);
final Uint8List bytes = f.readAsBytesSync();

return channel = ClientChannel(
  deviceIp,
  port: 6053,
  options: ChannelOptions(
    credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
      certificates: myPath,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Can someone answer with working secure grpc server and client example?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [test cases of grpc-dart](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/test/round_trip_test.dart#L104-L126)

Server:

```
final server = Server([YourServerClass()]);
await server.serve(
  port: portNumber,
  security: ServerTlsCredentials(
    certificate: File('crtFilePath/file.crt').readAsBytesSync(),
    privateKey: File('keycrtFilePath/file.key').readAsBytesSync(),
  ),
);
```

Client:

```
import 'package:grpc/src/client/http2_connection.dart';

FixedConnectionClientChannel(
  Http2ClientConnection(
    serverAddress,
    portNumber,
    ChannelOptions(
      credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
        certificates: File('crtFilePath/file.crt').readAsBytesSync(),
        authority: 'localhost',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


class FixedConnectionClientChannel extends ClientChannelBase {
  final Http2ClientConnection clientConnection;
  List<ConnectionState> states = <ConnectionState>[];
  FixedConnectionClientChannel(this.clientConnection) {
    clientConnection.onStateChanged = (c) => states.add(c.state);
  }
  @override
  ClientConnection createConnection() => clientConnection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you much but the same answer is posted on my question:

```dart
class MyChannelCredentials extends ChannelCredentials {
  final Uint8List? certificateChain;
  final Uint8List? privateKey;

  MyChannelCredentials({
    Uint8List? trustedRoots,
    this.certificateChain,
    this.privateKey,
    String? authority,
    BadCertificateHandler? onBadCertificate,
  }) : super.secure(
            certificates: trustedRoots,
            authority: authority,
            onBadCertificate: onBadCertificate);

  @override
  SecurityContext get securityContext {
    final ctx = super.securityContext;
    if (certificateChain != null) {
      ctx.useCertificateChainBytes(certificateChain);
    }
    if (privateKey != null) {
      ctx.usePrivateKeyBytes(privateKey);
    }
    return ctx;
  }
}

final cred = MyChannelCredentials(
  trustedRoots: File('pems/ca-cert.pem').readAsBytesSync(),
  certificateChain: File('pems/client-cert.pem').readAsBytesSync(),
  privateKey: File('pems/client-key.pem').readAsBytesSync(),
  authority: 'localhost',
);
```